# Accesssing model attribute in JPA doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am having problems accessing a model attribute in my controller, using Spring.

When adding to the model, I write the status code as a key and the enumeration name as a value. The status code is e.g. `AVAILABLE`, `NOTAVAILABLE`, etc.:

```
String code = status.getCode();
String enumerationName = enumerationService.getEnumerationName(status, currentLocale);
model.addAttribute(code, enumerationName);
```

On my JPA page, I am trying to access the corresponding value using the key (status code, e.g. `AVAILABLE`):

```
<div data-availability>
    <c:forEach items="${StockLevelDeliveryStatus.values()}" var="status">
        <c:set var="textStyle" value="text-success" />
        <c:if test="${status.code.toLowerCase() ==  'notavailable'}">
            <c:set var="textStyle" value="" />
        </c:if>
        <div class="d-none display-22 pb-2 ${textStyle}" data-availability-item data-${status.code.toLowerCase()}>
            ${status}
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

For example, the value of status is `AVAILABLE` and this is what is output in `${status}`. However, I want the value `AVAILABLE` to be used as a key to return me the correct value that I set in the model above. If I change the `${status}` statement to, say, `${AVAILABLE}` instead, which is the concrete key, the appropriate value from the model is returned:

```
<div class="d-none display-22 pb-2 ${textStyle}" data-availability-item data-${status.code.toLowerCase()}>
    ${AVAILABLE}
</div>
```

If I understand it correctly, then instead of passing the enum value as a key, I need to somehow teach Spring to search in the model for the appropriate key.

As recommended in one of the replies, I also tried writing the `Map<StockLevelDeliveryStatus, String>` directly into the model:

```
Map<StockLevelDeliveryStatus, String> statusMap = new HashMap<StockLevelDeliveryStatus, String>();
for (StockLevelDeliveryStatus status : StockLevelDeliveryStatus.values()) {
    statusMap.put(status, enumerationService.getEnumerationName(status, currentLocale));
}
model.addAttribute("statusMap", statusMap);
```

And the JSP accordingly:

```
<div data-availability>
    <c:forEach items="${StockLevelDeliveryStatus.values()}" var="status">
        <c:set var="textStyle" value="text-success" />
        <c:if test="${status.code.toLowerCase() ==  'notavailable'}">
            <c:set var="textStyle" value="" />
        </c:if>
        <div class="d-none display-22 pb-2 ${textStyle}" data-availability-item data-${status.code.toLowerCase()}>
            ${statusMap[status]}
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Here it already fails when accessing the model, because with this approach I do not get any output on the JSP.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Could you try to explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve? You're assigning each enum constant from `StockLevelDeliveryStatus` to the `status` variable in a loop, and then printing the `status` variable. This will, unsurprisingly, print all enum constants from `StockLevelDeliveryStatus`. What behavior did you expect instead?

Comment: I have a weird feeling you want sth like `${${status}}`. Nesting EL expressions is not supported, though

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply put a `Map<StockLevelDeliveryStatus, String>` into the model? You could then simply use `${statusMap[status]}`.

Comment: Thank you! I have implemented your approach and revised my post accordingly.

Comment: Why is the variable called `statusMap` in the Java code and `hashMap` in the JSP?

Comment: Also, a minor tweak but `EnumMap` is more performant for maps with enum keys